# Como compactar uma pasta com tudo dentro usando zipfile em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo-zip

Estou querendo compactar um arquivo e uma pasta que tem vários arquivos dentro em um único arquivo .zip usando Python. O script é p seguinte:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile,ZIP_DEFLATED

def zipar(lista):
    with ZipFile('teste.zip','w',ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
        for i in lista:
            z.write(i)

zipar(['registro.py','Tudo'])
```

Quando rodo o script, ele compacta "registro.py" e a pasta "Tudo", porém os arquivos que estão dentro da pasta "Tudo" original não são compactados junto, ou seja, a pasta é compactada vazia. Como conserto isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que precisas de especificar recursivamente os diretorios/ficheiros dentro do diretorio `Tudo` e outros que possas querer, consegues isto via [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk), e devido ao facto de `registro.py` não estar no mesmo diretório (`Tudo`) implica que tenhas de usar [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html):

```
import zipfile as zipf
import os

def zipar(arqs):
    with zipf.ZipFile('teste.zip','w', zipf.ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
        for arq in arqs:
            if(os.path.isfile(arq)): # se for ficheiro
                z.write(arq)
            else: # se for diretorio
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(arq):
                    for f in files:
                        z.write(os.path.join(root, f))

zipar(['registro.py','Tudo'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use o módulo [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) que é bem mais prático.

Exemplo:

```
...
├─── minha_pasta/
│    ├── tudo/
│    │   ├── sub_pasta_1/
│    │   │   ├── arquivo_1
│    │   │   └── arquivo_2
│    │   ├── sub_pasta_2/
│    │   │   ├── arquivo_3
│    │   │   └── arquivo_4
│    │   └── sub_pasta_3/
│    │       ├── arquivo_5
│    │       └── arquivo_6
│    └── registro.py
└─── script.py
```

**script.py**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from shutil import make_archive

make_archive('pasta_compactada', 'zip', 'minha_pasta')
```

**Resultado**:

```
pasta_compactada.zip/
├── tudo/
│   ├── sub_pasta_1/
│   │   ├── arquivo_1
│   │   └── arquivo_2
│   ├── sub_pasta_2/
│   │   ├── arquivo_3
│   │   └── arquivo_4
│   └── sub_pasta_3/
│       ├── arquivo_5
│       └── arquivo_6
└── registro.py
```

Para detalhes da função cheque a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#archiving-operations)

Caso tua estrutura de diretórios não esteja da maneira que tu quer é só ajustar com comandos como `shutil.copy2`.

Comment: Há um problema com essa solução, como pões vários fidheiros/diretorios dentro do mesmo zip? neste caso os `['registro.py','Tudo']`?

Comment: Ele compacta tudo o que tiver dentro de `/path/da/pasta` copiando a estrutura de diretórios e arquivos dentro de `zipfile_name.zip`. 
Teste aqui no meu computador antes de postar a resposta e está tudo certo. Testou aí?

Comment: Sim, mas como colocas o ficheiro `registro.py` para dentro desse zip? Tal como é pedido na pergunta deves colocar todos os ficheiros/diretorios que estiverem na lista de entrada no mesmo `ficheiro.zip`, neste caso o ficheiro `registro.py`, e o diretorio `Tudo` (e todos os seus conteudos)

Comment: Esse comando copia a estrutura do diretório. É só ajustar o diretório como tu quer e compactar. Não entendi o mistério

Comment: Mas no caso deste problema o ficheiro `registo.py` não está dentro desse diretório, mas é suposto coloca-lo no mesmo zip destino

Comment: Editei a resposta. O que quis dizer é que ele pode copiar os arquivos e pasta que ele quer para uma pasta temporária, compactar e excluir a pasta temporária. Talvez nem precisa da pasta temporária, depende de como ele está trabalhando com essa estrutura.

Comment: Sim, isso dá mas implica mudar a estrutura original de pastas/ficheiros, no entanto dá sim

Comment: Enfim, eu só quis complementar a tua resposta, que acho ser a mais correta dessa pergunta. Porém, alguém vai cair nessa questão numa pesquisa pelo google, e achei interessante disponibilizar uma resposta diferente que pode se aplicar melhor para outras situações.
Obrigado pelos feedbacks, com certeza melhorou a qualidade da resposta. :)

Comment: De nada, sim a tua resposta é adequada quando queremos um diretório e todos os seus conteudos, também não está errada